# Extend mysqli_result

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I have extended PHP's `mysqli` class, which works fine. But how can I make it return a custom result object (or a boolean for insert/update/delete etc) when querying?

```
namespace MyApp;
class MySQLi extends \mysqli {
    public function query($query, $resultmode = null) {
        // This needs to return a MySQLiResult or a boolean
    }
}
class MySQLiResult extends \mysqli_result {
}
```

Doing this I can return a MySQLiResult object, but I can't figure out how to return a boolean for non select based queries:

```
public function query($query, $resultmode = null) {
    $this->real_query($query); 
    return new MySQLiResult($this);
}
```

**Update:**

This is what I ended up using:

```
class MySQLi extends \mysqli {

    public function query($query, $resultmode = null) {
        $result = parent::query($query, $resultmode);
        return is_bool($result) ? $result : new MySQLiResult($result);
    }

}


class MySQLiResult {

    private $result;

    public function __construct(mysqli_result $result) {
        $this->result = $result;
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->result, $name), $arguments);
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->result->$name = $value;
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        return $this->result->$name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the simplest thing to do would be treat your `MySQLiResult` class as a decorator for `mysqli_result`. For example

```
class MySQLiResult
{
    private $result;

    public function __construct(\mysqli_result $result)
    {
        $this->result = $result;
    }
}
```

You could then proxy method calls to the internal result and decorate (add functionality) where required.

Comment: True, I was trying to avoid doing that though.

Comment: @Petah You could still extend `mysqli_result` however there's no way I can see to return your class without first getting a normal result then adapting it.

Comment: Well you can, if you use `$this->real_query($query); return new MySQLiResult($this);` but that doesn't return a boolean for non select based queries.

Comment: @Peta *you* can use that (it is your question). I use PDO ;)

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but close enough

Answer (score 4):

Phil's answer is OK, but it is possible to just extend MySQLi_Result by checking `mysqli::field_count`.
Checkout the [documentation](https://www.php.net/mysqli_field_count) for `mysqli::field_count`

> This function can be useful when using the mysqli_store_result() function to determine if the query should have produced a non-empty result set or not without knowing the nature of the query.

This is just what we needed.

```
public MySQL extends MySQLi
{
    public function query($query)
    {
        if ($this->real_query($query)) {
            if ($this->field_count > 0) {
                return new MySQL_Result($this);
            }
            return true;
        }

        throw new MySQL_Exception($this->error, $this->errno);
    }
}
```

Now you can extend your result class from MySQLi_Result and implement some useful interfaces like `SeekableIterator` so you can use `foreach` on your resultset:

```
class MySQL_Result extends MySQLi_Result implements Countable, SeekableIterator, ArrayAccess
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: From PHP v5.4+ mysqli_result implemnts Traversable interface so one is already able to loop through the result set using foreach loop syntax like `foreach($mysqli->query($SQL) as $row){...}`