# How to make instance of one class to be instance of another class

Tags: php, oop

I have custom db class which extends MySQLi class
MySQLi->query() method returns obejct with MySQLi_Result class, but I want to extend funcionality of this class and somehow make result object to be MyResult class. Something like this:

```
class MyResult extends MySQLi_Result{
  function abc(){
    //...
  }
}

class MyDB extends MySQLi{
  function q($query){
    return /*Here some magic*/ $this->query();
  }
}

$db=new MyDB();
$res=$db->q('SEL...');
$res->abc();
```

How to do this?

EDIT:
Some say that this is duplicate, but problem here is deeper!
I need that $result object would act like Mysqli_result class obect, so the old code would work.
So I need that, I can call original Mysqli_result methods like:

```
$res->fetch_assoc();

//but not
$res->result->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extend mysqli_result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195377/extend-mysqli-result)

Comment: Just add a method "fetch_assoc" in your MyResult. It will delegate to the same method in MySQLi_Result (function fetch_assoc(){return $this->result->fetch_assoc();}). The bonus is that you can also add your own logic to this function (like count the nomber of fetches your page does, for example), thought, your old code will still work.

Comment: @Mironor OP could also use `mysqli_fetch_object ( mysqli_result $result [, string $class_name [, array $params ]] )` but that would not return a custom `MySqli_Result` class but a custom object for the queried data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply the [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)
So your code will be:

```
 class MyResult {

      private $result;

      function __construct(MySQLi_Result $result)
      {
          $this->result = result;
      }
    //Here some methods that use $this->result as you wish
    }

    class MyDB extends MySQLi{
      function q($query){
        return new MyResult($this->query($query));
      }
    }

    $db=new MyDB();
    $res=$db->q('SEL...');
    $res->myMethod();
```

Comment: Accepting this answer. Combined with comment it solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

`class MyDB extends MySQLi{
  function q($query){
  return new MyResult($this->query());
  }
}`

The MyResult would need a constructor that stores the output of query() and wraps it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this.

```
class MyDb extends MySQLi {
    function query($query) {
        $result = parent::query($sQuery);
        return new MyDbResult($result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've understood your question correctly, but it could look something like this.

```
class MyResult extends MySQLi_Result{
 function __Contstruct($ob)
 {
    return $this->abc($ob);
 }
 function abc($object){
  //your magic
 }
}

class MyDB extends MySQLi{
  function q($query){
    $ob = $this->query($query);
   return new MyResult($ob);
  }
}
```